# Error : std:: out of range. where is out of range problem?

Tags: c++

Given the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    
    vector<int> v;
    v.emplace_back(1);
    v.emplace_back(2);
    
    for(int i = 2; i < n; i++){ // Is this problem point?
        int data = v.at(i-1) + v.at(i-2);
        v.emplace_back(data);
    }
    
    cout << v.at(n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

this code has Error that is out of range.
I think that for loop has problem.
but I'm not sure where is out of range.
Is vector container index starting 0?

Comment: Try running your code through a debugger line by line and see what happens in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

In each iteration of `for(int i = 2; i < n; i++)` you add one element to `v`. After the loop `v` contains `max(2, n)` elements.
The problem is caused by

```
cout << v.at(n);
```

with `n >= 2`. The last valid index is `v.size() - 1`. But to print the last value of a vector you can simply use:

```
cout << v.back();
```